# Sql to linq grouped by join

Tags: sql, linq, .net-core

I have a sql query right now. And i'm trying to turn it to linq. Can anyone help me with it?

```
SELECT s1.id AS "SahaTespitId", s1.tespit_baslangic_zamani AS "TespitBaslangicZamani", 
s1.tespit_bitis_zamani AS "TespitBitisZamani", s2.atanan_personel AS "AktiviteAtananPersonel", 
s3.id AS "BasvuruNo"
FROM sd_dosya_birey AS s
INNER JOIN (select birey_id,saha_tespit_id from sd_inceleme_cevaplar group by birey_id,saha_tespit_id) AS s0 ON s.id = s0.birey_id 
INNER JOIN (select id,aktivite_id,tespit_baslangic_zamani,tespit_bitis_zamani from sd_saha_tespiti group by id,aktivite_id,tespit_baslangic_zamani,tespit_bitis_zamani) AS s1 ON s0.saha_tespit_id = s1.id
INNER JOIN sd_aktivite AS s2 ON s1.aktivite_id = s2.id
INNER JOIN sd_basvuru AS s3 ON s2.basvuru_id = s3.id
```

Comment: A good start would be to find an O/R mapper that supports LINQ and create a class model that maps to the database.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.